# Convert a SQL query with between to Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've trying for days to run a SQL query with a between operator with sequelize literal in node.js but I'm totally unable. The query works fine in SQL but I can implement it in sequelize. Can anyone help me please? This is the SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM vs_app_demoes.order_planned WHERE
  433869 BETWEEN
  cast(substr(cast(barcode AS CHAR),1,6) AS SIGNED) AND
  cast(substr(cast(barcode AS CHAR),1,6) AS SIGNED) + barcodeunits
  AND paneno = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `BETWEEN` with two `<=` and `>=` joined by AND:

```js
const prders = await OrderPlanned({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      Sequelize.where(Sequilize.literal('cast(substr(cast(barcode AS CHAR),1,6) AS SIGNED)'), '<=', 433869),
      Sequelize.where(Sequilize.literal('(cast(substr(cast(barcode AS CHAR),1,6) AS SIGNED) + barcodeunits)'), '>=', 433869),
      paneno: 2
    ]
  }
})
```